# Ruby how to override ruby sort_by

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a method that uses the functionality of Array's `sort_by` method.

Imagine I have this data

```
data_array = [{project: 'proj', version: '1.1'}, {project: 'proj2', version: '1.11'}, {project: 'proj3', version: '1.2'}]
```

I want to be able to call the method like this:

```
data_array.natural_sort_by{|x| x[:version] }
```

The actual call that happens would achieve something like this:

```
data_array.sort_by{|x| MyModule.naturalize_str(x[:version]) }
```

Heres my current unworking code:

```
Array.module_eval do 
  def natural_sort_by(&block)
    sort_by{|x| Rearmed.naturalize_str(eval(block))}
  end
end
```

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you know about the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) module?

Comment: Yes I do. I needed to solve the main problem first. I will probably get there although I don't know it will be applicable to all Enumerable's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Array
  def natural_sort_by
    sort_by{|x| MyModule.naturalize_str(yield(x))}
  end
end
```

or

```
class Array
  def natural_sort_by &block
    sort_by{|x| MyModule.naturalize_str(block.call(x))}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The hash key references are not of the correct type.  Consider changing this `x['version']` to `x[:version]` to properly reference the `:version` key.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @WestonGanger No. This is an important point. It is your responsibility to make the question clear.